# Passing numpy arrays to Java using Jpype

Tags: java, python, numpy

I am trying to convert a numpy array into a Java-like array using JPype's JArray command.

```
values = valBD.ReadAsArray()
JArray(float, values.ndim)(values)
```

leads to the following error message:

> JArray(float, values.ndim)(values)
>   File
>   "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\jpype_jarray.py",
>   line 125, in JArray elif issubclass(t,
>   _jclass._JAVAOBJECT):
>
> **TypeError**: issubclass() arg 2 must be a class or tuple of classes

Do you habe any suggesions?
Thanks a lot,
Martwig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPype is expecting a list or list of lists, not a numpy array.

Try this:

```
values = valBD.ReadAsArray()
JArray(float, values.ndim)(values.tolist())
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answer doesn't work. Try this:

```
a = JArray(JFloat,1)([1.5,2.0])
```